# Kubernetes - Communicating b/w services

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 2 services deployed and the services are exposed to internet thru ingress. I am able to access the services outside the cluster using the ingress host. How to access the service within the cluster? Do i need to use the same ingress host approach for the service to access within the cluster?

So, If i deploy 2 services( Service A & Service B) in parallel, How can i configure service A to talk to service B in the service A property file?

Currently, we have deployed our applications into Linux VM's and service A proeprty file will have `http:<serviceB_VIP>/api/v1/...`

How to achieve the same thing kubernetes cluster? How to configure the service B URL in service A property before the deployment so that both the service can be deployed in parallel.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `serviceName:` and `servicePort:` in [Ingress `backend:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#ingressbackend-v1beta1-extensions) are the same objects one would use to communicate from within the cluster. In fact, that's why almost every object's name in kubernetes must be DNS-compatible: because they are often exposed by `kube-dns`.

So, for a `Service` with `metadata.name: foo` and `metadata.namespace: bar`, the service is accessible from within the cluster as `foo.bar.svc.cluster.local`, containing all the `port:`s from that same `Service`.

I highly, highly, highly recommend reading the kubernetes documentation about Services

Comment: correct, where `<port>` will be the *Service*'s port, not any `containerPort` declarations on the downstream Pods

Answer (score 0):

You can expose service within the cluster via ClusterIP.

There are 4 types of service in kubernetes.

1. `NodePort`:- expose service on Kubernetes Nodes port.
2. `ClusterIP`:- You can expose your service with the cluster only
3. `LoadBalancer`:- You can expose your service on Load  Balancer which creates one nginx load balancer in GCP.
4. `External name`